# dont work CJuiAutoComplete in main layout

Tags: php, yii

i will show search form in **main layout**.i should set autocomplete to the field.
i use CJuiAutoComplete .this widget dose not work when site load home page but i go to other page everthing is ok and this widget work correctly.

```
<form action="" method="post">
                    <h2>search place</h2>
                    <label for="city">city 
                            <?php                            
$city=array('kam','lid','bojnood','joka','hemri');
                            $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete',array(
                               'name' =>'city',
                                'source'=>array_values($city),
                                'htmlOptions'=>array(
                                    'style'=>'direction:rtl,width:100%,text-align:right'
                                )
                            ));
</label>
<input type="submit" value="جستجو" class="search"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found solution but this is not interest.i added jquery ui and command in main page.

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCoreScript('jquery.ui');
?>
</head>
<body>
<script>
jQuery('#city').autocomplete({'source':['kam','lid','bojnood','joka','hemri']});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```